# I get "Error establishing proxy connection" when trying to visit a page out of corporate domain using cypress in spite of setting proxy

Tags: node.js, npm, proxy, cypress

I am trying to test a webpage using Cypress. In the test I visit a page using cy.visit() command. When I visit a page in the corporate domain it passes successfully. But, when I test a page out of corporate domain if fails.
Here is the test.

```
describe('empty spec', () => {
  it('passes', () => {
    cy.visit('https://www.google.com/')
  })
})
```

I get this error when running the test:

```
CypressError: `cy.visit()` failed trying to load:

https://www.google.com/

We attempted to make an http request to this URL but the request failed without a response.  

We received this error at the network level:

  > Error: Error establishing proxy connection. Response from server was: HTTP/1.1 407 Proxy 
Authentication Required ( Forefront TMG requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied.  )
```

I set proxies as below.

```
npm set proxy http://name:password@gtpproxy.proxy.com:8080
npm set https-proxy http://name:password@gtpproxy.proxy.com:8080
```

When I check proxies using

```
npm config list
```

I see that proxies are set properly.

But still I get the error.

How can I fix the error?